# In Windows 8, how to know exactly which ISO file is mounted in a virtual drive?

Tags: windows-8, mount, iso-image, virtual-drive

Windows 8 has the ability to natively mount ISO images. But how to know which ISO file is mounted in a virtual drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the PowerShell prompt:

**To find the drive letter corresponding to an ISO**:

```
Get-DiskImage -ImagePath "full_path_to_image" | Get-Volume
```

**To find the ISO corresponding to a drive letter**:

```
Get-Volume -DriveLetter F | Get-DiskImage
```

"F" is obviously the drive letter. Also, you can try omitting "-DriveLetter" to shorten the command. If you omit both "-DriveLetter" *and* the letter itself, you should see info for all volumes.

Comment: I can't do +1 in your answer, I don't have enought reputation, sorry  :(    but many thanks

Comment: @Hugo: Don't worry about the upvote, but you *can* accept the answer if it helped you. :)